# How can I print several random file names from a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder with 310 txt files and I want to print 248 random file names (without repetition) from these txt files. I have tried out the following code, but it only outputs 1 random file name instead of 248 file names at once.

```py
import os
import random
path = "C:\Python\Python37-32\lindenberg_txt"
files = os.listdir(path)
index = random.randrange(0, len(files))
print(files[index])
```

Python version used: 3.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os

import random

path = r"C:\Python\Python37-32\lindenberg_txt"

files = os.listdir(path)

random.shuffle(files)

print(files[0:248])
```

Answer (score 0):

random.choice returns a random element in a list
you can use it with a loop to make a new list

```
new_list = []
index = random.randint(0,len(files)-1)
for i in range(index)
     new_list += [random.choice(files)]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```py
import os
import random
path = "C:\Python\Python37-32\lindenberg_txt"
files = os.listdir(path)
print([files[random.randint(0, len(files) - 1)] for i in range(0, 248)])
```